# forEach not returning values as expected JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am checking for `undefined` and want to replace with `""`

I have:

```
let values = [ ['header1','header2'], 
                ['AAA', undefined],
                [2, 'BB'],
                [undefined, 'CCC'],
                ['AAA', 4],
              ];
values.forEach(function (row) {
  row.forEach(function(col) {
    col= col===undefined ? "":col;
  });
});
```

It returns the original array values.

But I am expecting

```
[ ['header1','header2'], 
  ['AAA', ""],
  [2, 'BB'],
  ["", 'CCC'],
  ['AAA', 4],
 ];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `row.forEach(function(col,idx,arr) {
    arr[idx]= col===undefined ? "":col;...`

Comment: You can't compare to undefined directly, you'll have to use `typeof(col)==="undefined"` or if you're fine with null being replaced too `col ?? ""`

Comment: @SweetSheep Comparing `=== undefined` is totally fine, `typeof` is not needed.

Comment: @SweetSheep of course you can compare to `undefined` directly ... `a === undefined` is equivaltent to `typeof a === "undefined"`

Comment: @derpirscher they're not quite equivalent - if `a` hasn't even been declared then `a === undefined` will be a `ReferenceError`, but `typeof a === "undefined"` will be `true`, with no error. But other than that edge case, you're correct that they're identical.

Comment: @RobinZigmond If you were to nitpick, `undefined` could also be shadowed, but that's obscure. And `col` absolutely has been declared in the above example.

Comment: in the code as shown in the OP, sure. I was responding just to the comment which, by referring to a variable `a` that doesn't exist in the OP, seemed to be making a general point